# Педача данных между фрагментами и их просмотр в новом окне

Tags: android, android-fragment, передача-данных

Имеется одна пустая активность с `Frame_layout (match_parent)` для двух фрагментов. В одном находится `ListView`, в другом `TextView`. Нужно при выборе элемента из `ListView` в первом фрагменте , передавать `getItemAtPosition (String значение)` в `TextView` второго фрагмента. Попытался сделать это через интерфейс, вызывая метод в 1 фрагменте, передавая параметр и переопределяя метод в активити, но приложение аварийно закрывается при нажатии. Искал информацию на различных источниках, ситуация такая: либо оба фрагмента находятся рядом на одном активити (что мне не подходит); либо передача идет с Активити на Активити. Не понимаю как передавать данные между фрагментами с последующим его открытием. Код ниже:
`FirstFragment`:

```
 list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String selectedItem = (String)list.getItemAtPosition(position);
                OnSelectedItemListener listener = (OnSelectedItemListener) getActivity();
                listener.onItemClick(selectedItem);
                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentBox, new ReportViewFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }
        });
public interface OnSelectedItemListener{
        void onItemClick (String selectionItem);
    }
```

`SecondFragment`:

---

```
public void setTitle (String item){
    TextView textView = getView().findViewById(R.id.title);
    textView.setText(item);
}
```

`Activity`:

---

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(String selectionItem) {
    ReportViewFragment frView = (ReportViewFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentBox);
    if(frView != null){
        frView.setTitle(selectionItem);
    }
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый.

Answer (score 0):

Передать данные в другой фрагмент можно при переходе на него из первого фрагмента. Переход делается так:

```
Fragment fragment = new SecondFragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(key, value); // тут нужно положить ваш selectionItem
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

и дальше в втором фрагменте получаем данные в функции `onCreate()`:

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
if (bundle != null) {
   String selectionItem= bundle.getString(key, defaultValue);
} 
TextView textView = getView().findViewById(R.id.title);
textView.setText(selectionItem);
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо за ответ. Всё получилось)
Тоже пробовал этот вариант, но видимо что-то пропустил (или источник с ошибкой).